# Return type eliminated by erasure in Scala

Tags: scala

Consider the following Scala code snippet:

```
def func(param: Any): Int = param match {
  case f: (String => Int) => f("apple")
  case i: Int => i
}

println(func((s: String) => s.length))
```

Works as expected, however, at compilation I get the following warning:

```
<console>:11: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern String => Int is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
         case f: (String => Int) => f("apple")
```

How can I get rid of this warning message?

Thanks your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get the message is because of Java's generic [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). In this particular case, your function which is of type `Function[String, Int]` will be matched by any `Function[A, B]`.

In order to get rid of this warning you should use scala [typetags](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) which will allow you to differentiate between the different function types.

The code snippet is below,

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Answer {
 def function[A](param: A)(implicit tt: TypeTag[A]): String = param match {
   case f: (String => Int) @unchecked if typeOf[String => Int] =:= typeOf[A] => f("apple").toString
    case f: (Int => String) @unchecked if typeOf[Int => String] =:= typeOf[A] => f(32 + 1)
    case s: String => s"hello $s"
  }

  def main (args: Array[String]) {
     println(function((s: String) => s.length))
     println(function((i: Int) => i.toString))
     println(function("world"))
  }
}
```

The key part is to have an `implicit` `TypeTag[A]` which is added at compile time which includes the metadata that the function `typeOf` needs to check the types of `A` against anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the links! I've tried to fix the warning but failed. Now I have a theoretical knowledge what `TypeTag` means, furthermore, I've learnt that `case f: ((_) => (_)) =>` would not complain. However, in latter case the `f(...)` results in compiler error. Would you please so kind to give me some further hints how to proceed? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the explanatory code! It is really more precise, as we can now differentiate between String => Int and Int => String. I've tried it, but unfortunately the same warning comes, now two times.
I've tried the following: `type oneParamFuncType = _ => _`, and using `case f: oneParamFuncType ...` in both cases, however, this leads to compiler error at function call. Without function call the compiler would be happy. Do you have any idea how to cast the generic `oneParamFuncType` to a specific one?

Comment: Ah, if you want to get rid of the compiler warning you just need to add the `@unchecked` annotation to parameter, I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer!